# How do I find $M_{B<-e}(id)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we let $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be a linear transformation. Let $B=\{v_1,v_2\}$ with $ v_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\1  
\end{bmatrix}$ and  $ v_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0
\\1  
\end{bmatrix}$ and let $e$ be the standard basis for $R^2$. Suppose $M_{B<-B}(T) = \begin{bmatrix}
1&2
\\3&4  
\end{bmatrix}$ How do I find $M_{B<-e}(id)$? I understand that I must take this $id$ matrix put $e$ inside of it then change the basis to $b$ which is $v_1,v_2$. But what is $id$?

Comment: id is the *identity transformation*, defined by $T(x) = x$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom how do I find that then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
id(e_1) = e_1 = (1)v_1 + (-1)v_2\\
id(e_2) = e_2 = (0)v_1 + (1)v_2
$$
this determines the columns of the desired matrix.  That is,
$$
M_{B \leftarrow e}(id) = \pmatrix{1&0\\-1&1}
$$
Notably, this is the inverse of the matrix $[v_1\; v_2] = M_{e \leftarrow B}(id)$.

Comment: could you explain this part?  $$
id(e_1) = e_1 = (1)v_1 + (-1)v_2\\
id(e_2) = e_2 = (0)v_1 + (1)v_2
$$

Comment: What's there to explain? Do you understand that the equations are true statements?

Comment: nvm I understand now, thanks a lot for your answer