# what is $M_{e<-e}(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we let $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be a linear transformation. Let $B=\{v_1,v_2\}$ with $ v_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1
\\1  
\end{bmatrix}$ and  $ v_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0
\\1  
\end{bmatrix}$ and let $e$ be the standard basis for $R^2$. Suppose $M_{B<-B}(T) = \begin{bmatrix}
1&2
\\3&4  
\end{bmatrix}$

I found $M_{B<-e}(id) =  
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0
\\-1&1  
\end{bmatrix}$ but what is $M_{e<-e}(T)$?

Comment: Similar to what you asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2054828/9464

Comment: looking at that I am unable to get the answer still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
M_{e \leftarrow e}[T] = M_{e \leftarrow B}[id]\;M_{B \leftarrow B}[T] \;M_{B\leftarrow e}[id] = \\
M_{e \leftarrow B}[id]\;M_{B \leftarrow B}[T] \; (M_{e \leftarrow B}[id])^{-1}
$$